# Why was my tag wiki edit on dllexport rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

Three people rejected it with a reason:

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service,
>   or is deliberately destructive

I don't think my edit was destructive in any way, and when it comes to "promoting products" I just reworded the original. I don't think it's any sort of promotion either.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6659813

It would be nice if one could explain what's wrong instead of downvoting. I would want to know how to make valid edits.

Comment: Besides the first piece being a sentence fragment, I see nothing wrong with the edit. You *did* remove the "Use this tag when" guidance, but I'm not sure it was all that valuable to start with.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Tag guidance should be in tag excerpt rather than in a tag wiki, because it's an excerpt, which is visible when user tags questions. See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/ Nevertheless explicit guidance "Use this tag when..." is sometimes omitted, because for some tags it's obvious that tag should be used for the thing described by an excerpt.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

It seems that it's reviewers who made a mistake. I have posted it again with slightly modified sentences and edit was accepted.

If you see any mistakes in my edit please correct me and improve tag wiki.

Comment: You can choose to ignore the feedback you've gotten on the edit, but you're not proving anything to anyone by insisting that three reviewers in a row "made a mistake". Whether your edit was better or worse is very debatable, and I've submitted a new edit that takes into account the feedback you've received here. You can either choose to learn from the answers you've gotten or you can try to debate it all away, but I don't know why you bothered asking this question if you weren't interested in the possibility that it wasn't just a mistake.

Comment: @sphanley Question was rejected for the reason `"This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive"`, so I wanted to know why. Three reviewers gave it as exact reason, so I thought there's maybe something in it. But it looks like it's not an issue. Simple as that.

Comment: This is the last I'm going to say on the topic, but as I've pointed out twice already, you effectively removed a section of the tag wiki which explicitly gave guidance on when to use the tag. You can insist that three reviewers in a row independently made the exact same mistake if you want, but the possibility that they thought by "destructive" they were talking about your removal of content seems **much more likely**. The votes on our respective answers should indicate to you that I'm not alone in feeling that way.

Comment: @sphanley thanks for your edit, but you have re-added section, which does not make sense.

Comment: @sphanley Tag guidance should be in tag excerpt! In general you won't find tag guidance in any of the tag wikis. Sometimes explicit guidance is omitted in excerpt, because it's obvious from description of the subject that tag should be used for described subject.

Answer (score 7):

In comments you've acknowledged that the text of your edit still reflects poor English. Saying that the English is bad after your edit because it was bad beforehand fundamentally misses the point of an edit. If you're editing something bad, don't just move parts of it around but ultimately leave it bad -- make it good! An edit where you fix something minor, but still leave obvious bigger flaws intact is a waste of both your time and the time of the people reviewing it.

If you're interested in learning more about this point, there's lots of discussion that's been had in the past regarding when an edit is "too minor". I'd argue that "too minor" would have been a better reason to reject this edit, although the fact that you removed the "this tag should be used when..." language *could* be construed as destructive.

Comment: O.K., but English is a bit off topic. I was stunned by the fact that 3 reviewers marked it as "promoting products" or "deliberately destructive". If it was one person, I would have ignored it. But if there are three, then I start to think that maybe I am missing something... So, I am asking about actual reason of rejection

Comment: Nobody can read the reviewer's minds, but as I mentioned the most likely explanation is that you removed the explicit wording of "This Tag should be used when [...]". While it was poorly worded, that is a useful component of a tag wiki and a good edit would have improved it rather than removing it (which is to say "destroying" it). And I don't really see how poor English is off-topic when discussing the quality of an edit.

Comment: 2. Primary point of the edit was not to fix grammar. If you look closely it only mentions C, while "dllexport" is also C++ directive. I have moved this into tag excerpt earlier (so I don't repeat excerpt in tag wiki) and that edit was accepted. I have edited this tag after I met C++ question involving dllexport. I have found tag excerpt stating that it's C (suggesting C only) directive misleading.

Comment: You don't have to argue with me about it, I didn't vote on your edit. You just asked for an explanation of possible reasons your edit was rejected so I'm trying to analyze it for you. I don't even have edit review privileges yet and I don't offhand know anything about dllexport, so it's all the same to me.

Comment: Additionally, it's unlikely that an edit reviewer will be aware of any other edits that you have made which may be related, so even if you moved info from the tag wiki to the tag excerpt, it's still just going to appear to the reviewer that you reduced the amount of information in the wiki. They're reviewing this edit on its merits alone.

Comment: I am not arguing. I just want to provide a context. I was expecting simple answers on this specific reason of rejection.  Either it's reviewers error or something is wrong and I don't want to do such mistake again.

Comment: Also don't exaggerate bad grammar. First sentence is wrong, but the rest is IMO acceptable and much better than original, which even does not make sense. AFAIK tag wiki is about incremental changes and improvement - not fixing all errors at once. There are much worse edits, which are being accepted and more minor ones.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say why exactly that reason was chosen. Possibly the first reviewer mis-clicked, and the subsequent reviewers just went with it.

Regardless of the specific reason, rejection seems appropriate to me. The proposed replacement still does not demonstrate good English and is not particularly informative.

Comment: Well, I know English is bad, because I was affected by the original. Why was original entry approved in the first place?

Comment: @sphanley O.K., but English is a bit off topic. I was stunned by the fact that 3 reviewers marked it as "promoting products" or "deliberately destructive". If it was one person, I would have ignored it. But if there are three, then I start to think that maybe I am missing something... So, I am asking about actual reason of rejection.